# FancyBox - “The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later.”

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm having trouble with displaying my images when I upload it on the server, if I preview the website from my DW it shows the images, when I upload it on the server it shows **“The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later.”**

Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#fancybox-manual-c").click(function() {
                $.fancybox.open([
                    {
                        href : '1.jpg',
                        title : 'Bioterapia Sanatatii'
                    },{
                        href : '2.jpg',
                        title : 'Bioterapia Sanatatii'
                    },{
                        href : '3.jpg',
                        title : 'Bioterapia Sanatatii'
                    },{
                        href : '4.jpg',
                        title : 'Bioterapia Sanatatii'
                    },{
                        href : '5.jpg',
                        title : 'Bioterapia Sanatatii'
                    },{
                        href : '6.jpg',
                        title : 'Bioterapia Sanatatii'
                    },{
                        href : '7.jpg',
                        title : 'Bioterapia Sanatatii'
                    },{
                        href : '8.jpg',
                        title : 'Bioterapia Sanatatii'
                    },{
                        href : '9.jpg',
                        title : 'Bioterapia Sanatatii'
                    },{
                        href : '10.jpg',
                        title : 'Bioterapia Sanatatii'
                    },{
                        href : '11.jpg',
                        title : 'Bioterapia Sanatatii'
                    },{
                        href : '12.jpg',
                        title : 'Bioterapia Sanatatii'
                    },{
                        href : '13.jpg',
                        title : 'Bioterapia Sanatatii'
                    },{
                        href : '14.jpg',
                        title : 'Bioterapia Sanatatii'
                    },{
                        href : '15.jpg',
                        title : 'Bioterapia Sanatatii'
                    },{
                        href : '16.jpg',
                        title : 'Bioterapia Sanatatii'
                    },{
                        href : '17.jpg',
                        title : 'Bioterapia Sanatatii'
                    },{
                        href : '18.jpg',
                        title : 'Bioterapia Sanatatii'
                    },
                ], {
                    helpers : {
                        thumbs : {
                            width: 75,
                            height: 50
                        }
                    }
                });
            });


        });
```

**UPDATE WITH THE ANSWER**

**Well, I found out what was wrong, It seems that Fancybox requires the terminal of the image to be CapsLock.**

So instead of:

```
                {
                    href : '1.jpg',
                    title : 'Bioterapia Sanatatii'
                },{
                    href : '2.jpg',
                    title : 'Bioterapia Sanatatii'
                }...and so on
```

We should write :

```
                {
                    href : '1.JPG',
                    title : 'Bioterapia Sanatatii'
                },{
                    href : '2.JPG',
                    title : 'Bioterapia Sanatatii'
                }...and so on
```

Hope this will help others with similar problems.

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle

Comment: @dave I will try to put one up now

Comment: use absolute paths instead of relative ones, so instead of `1.jpg` use `/path/to/pictures/directory/1.jpg`

Comment: @mateimihai I have done so, but i thought that was a problem so I moved the pictures to my main folder as my index page, that's why they are written only as 1.jpg, but I found the answer, I updated the question with the answer.

Comment: @dave I found the answer, I updated the question with the answer.

Comment: Coolest answer.. The image extension has to be in capital..wow nice alin

Comment: @dave Well, it's the first time it happened. I never had problems such as this using for example PrettyPhoto or other similar stuff but...oh well. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer update too.. I will keep this in mind,, I too use fancybox to display images and alerts

Comment: Well, I don't have/use Skype, I'm more of an email type of guy :) And I'm just starting to learn more and more about jquery and php now and I don't wanna bother you with stupid questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            {
                href : '1.JPG',
                title : 'Bioterapia Sanatatii'
            },{
                href : '2.JPG',
                title : 'Bioterapia Sanatatii'
            }
```

For those who come across similar issue.. Try image extension in capital as specified above by alin

Comment: Haha :D I would have answered it myself but I don't have the minimum of reputation (10) :))

Comment: Now I have exactly 10 :)) Thanks a lot Dave.